# How can I get and use app context root for a reactjs app at run time

Tags: facebook, apache, reactjs, webpack, websphere-liberty

I do not know what the public path of my reactjs app will be during build time. Is there a way I can get and use the context path at run time?

My app is created with the `create-react-app` script from facebook. I can use the `"homepage":"/some-context-root"` flag in package.json. The only problem is I do not know this during build time and more likely it will not be the root folder of my http server.

Comment: why not just omit that value? not sure what the problem is, to be honest. i have built a lot of react apps, but i have never needed any "context root".